# ontology find properties from class and it's subClass

Tags: sparql, ontology, protege

I am using Protege to create a ontology

Here is the concept of the ontology :

```
class : Human
dataProperties : 
    hasName ( Domain: Human)
    hasHeight ( Domain: Human)
    hasWeight ( Domain: Human)

class : Man    - subClassOf Human
dataProperties : 
    hasWife ( Domain: Man)
```

I want to use Sparql to Query the Class:Man's all Dataproperties
not only (hasWife) , but also (hasName, hasHeight, hasWeight)

Do I need to specify the DataProperties restriction like min:1?

The main goal here is to find 
If I want to create a individual type Class:Man

How do I find all properties it need ?

Because every man should have a name and height and weight.

Comment: I think this has been answered in another question. I can't search for it now, but searching about jena's listProperties may help.

Comment: Thanks you. After I post this question and keep searching for a while. Get a solution from 2 or 3 post.

Comment: Where did you find the answer?  I spent a few minutes looking for a duplicate, but I couldn't find one.  (I thought that there was one, though.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ```
> class : Human
> dataProperties : 
>     hasName ( Domain: Human)
>     hasHeight ( Domain: Human)
>     hasWeight ( Domain: Human)
>
> class : Man    - subClassOf Human
> dataProperties : 
>     hasWife ( Domain: Man)
> ```
>
> I want to use Sparql to Query the Class:Man's all Dataproperties not
>   only (hasWife) , but also (hasName, hasHeight, hasWeight)

First, remember that *classes* don't have properties in OWL. Properties can have domains and ranges, but all that means is that the subject (object) of an assertion is a member of the domain (range).  Although there *is* the notion of *class*, it's not quite the same as in an (single-dispatch) object oriented programming language, where properties "belong" to classes.

That said, it sounds like you're looking for all properties that have a domain that is Man or a superclass of Man.  (Note that I say "a domain", and not "the domain"; properties can have more than one domain. In fact, if you say that a domain of hasWife is Man, then then Human is also a property of hasWife;  after all, if you know that hasWife(x,y), you know that x must be a Human.) This isn't too hard:

```sql
select ?p where {
  ?p rdfs:domain ?class .
  :Man rdfs:subClassOf* ?class .
}
```

That says to find values of ?p that have a domain ?class where :Man is connected to ?class by a path of rdfs:subClassOf links.  The * notation means that the path can be any length, including zero.  WHen the path length is zero, it means that ?class is :Man.  You can actually write this query a bit more concisely if you use the ^ operator to make backward paths:

```sql
select ?p where {
  ?class ^rdfs:domain ?p ;
         ^rdfs:subClassOf* :Man
}
```

("a domain", because properties can have more than one domain.

Comment: Really Thanks you! The class concept part is helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Finally got a solution here !

Here is the sparql

```
PREFIX foaf: <http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/>
PREFIX rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>
PREFIX owl:  <http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#>
PREFIX dar:  <http://www.darrell.testSub#>

SELECT DISTINCT ?properties  ?superclass  ?propertyType
WHERE {    
dar:Man      rdfs:subClassOf*   ?superclass.
?properties  rdfs:domain        ?superclass.
?properties  rdf:type           ?propertyType
}
```

But there is still some problem.

#### First, I need DISTINCT or I will get 2 duplicate for each.

#### Second, I can't figure it out why it avoid the "Woman" class's properties.

```
Human ( human's properties)
    --Man ( man's properties ) 
    --Woman ( woman's properties )
```

after reasoning, I query about

< ?s rdfs:domain :Human>

It return ( human + man + woman )'s properties

If I use the sparql up there. I can only get ( human + man )'s properties.

Although this is exactly the result what I want but I can't figure it out why.

Comment: Can you provide a link to the question where you found an answer?

Comment: Also, if this isn't a complete answer to your question, then you should consider not posting it as an answer, but as an update to your question.

Comment: Sorry I forgot to save the link. I found the keyword "Property Path". There is a lot of useful information there!